# jQuery / AJAX - loading content into modal window, how to wait until load() is finished?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, load, wait

here's my function that is being called from within a `.click(function { loadBox(url); });` on a button:

```
var loadBox = function(url) {
    var mask = $('#mask');
    var box = $('#box');
    $(mask).fadeTo(600, 0.8).promise().done(function() {
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        var boxH = winH * 0.6;
        var boxW = winW * 0.8;

        $(box).css({
            width: boxW + 'px',
            height: boxH + 'px',
            top: ((winH - boxH) / 2) + 'px',
            left: ((winW - boxW) / 2) + 'px'
        });

        $(box).load(url).promise().done(function () {
            $(box).slideDown(300);
        });

        $(mask).click(function() {
            if($(':animated').length)
                return false;
            $(this).hide();
            $(box).hide();
        });
    });
}
```

`#mask`/`$(mask)` is a `<div>`-container that is just being used as an overlay,
`#box`/`$(box)` is another `<div>`-container that is loading a ***.php** page via `$(box).load(url)...` where *url* is something similiar to `/pages/player.php?match_id=1&player_id=15`.

Thus far it seems to be working, only one little thing is dirsturbing me, regarding:

```
$(box).load(url).promise().done(function () {
    $(box).slideDown(300);
});
```

I have a table with different players in it, when you click on a player's name `#box` pops up in the center of the screen, loaded with the `player.php` holding information about that player.

But if `#box` was loaded with some other player's information before, box will first show (`$(box).slideDown(300);`) and *afterwards* its content is changed - so you see the other player's information for about half a second before the new information is loaded.

I thought `<function>.promise().done(...` will wait till until `<function>` - in my case `.load(url)` is completed and only then execute everything within the `.done(function { });` scope, or am I incorrect?

What is the correct way to wait until the `.load(url)` call is finished before showing the `$(box)` using `.slideDown()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should use a callback function. When `.load` completes its task, it will fire the callback. So, you should change:

```
$(box).load(url).promise().done(function () {
    $(box).slideDown(300);
});
```

to:

```
$(box).load(url, function () {
    $(box).slideDown(300);
});
```

Also, you don't need to keep wrapping `box` in a jQuery method. This defeats the purpose of caching them in vars at the top of your script. So really, it should be:

```
box.load(url, function () {
    box.slideDown(300);
});
```

Same goes for other instances in your code where you're wrapping vars multiple times...

Answer (score 1):

`$.load` doesn't support promises, so you'll just have to pass in the callback function as an argument:

```
$(box).load(url, function () {
    $(box).slideDown(300);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `promise().done()`, just put your callback as the second argument to [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Okay, thank you. But when I just go with the callback for some reason I can click the `#mask` before the `#box` has shown. If I do that the `#mask` will `.hide()` and I do not have a way to close down `#box` anymore (hence currently I only have that way to "close" both `<div>` containers) - how do I prevent a `.click()` on the `#mask` to close down any the two containers until both containers finished animating?

Comment: in your mask click function you can check if the box is visible before you try to hide it. if(box.is(":visible"))

Comment: Thank you very much good sir. I Just understood (clicking very often really fast right after the function was executed) that there is a split second where none of the containers have the ':animated' selector, that made it possible to close the window before the content actually showed. I just added `if($(':animated').length || box.is(':visible'))` and it works like a charm!